# SQL stored procedure with CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello i have a quation with my stored procedure , i use 2 cases here , the first case it shows me right values and its OK, the second shows me only Null values in the field TirType , i don't understand what is the problem

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.YUITY
    SELECT     CAST(dbo.SC5116.CODE AS int) AS код, dbo.SC5116.DESCR AS Наименование,    
     CAST(dbo.SC3420.CODE AS int) AS TIR, dbo.SC3420.SP4947 AS Date, 
                  CASE WHEN SC3420.SP4949 <> '     0   ' THEN 'ПовышСтрах' ELSE 'ОснСтрах' END AS VID, 
                  CASE WHEN dbo.SC3420.SP9214 = '714' THEN '4v' END AS TirType
      FROM         dbo.SC3420 INNER JOIN
                  dbo.SC5116 ON dbo.SC3420.SP3422 = dbo.SC5116.ID
       WHERE     (dbo.SC3420.SP4947 <> '01.01.1753')
```

Comment: What should be displayed in the  `else` case

Comment: You are missing `AS` after `CREATE VIEW` and you are also missing `END` from your second CASE statement. Syntax aside, I suspect the reason it is showing `NULL` is because there are no rows where `dbo.SC3420.SP9214` is equal to `'714'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget `END` after `CASE`. It will return NULL if no ELSE is specified and value is not '714'.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.YUITY
AS
    SELECT     CAST(dbo.SC5116.CODE AS int) AS код, dbo.SC5116.DESCR AS Наименование,    
     CAST(dbo.SC3420.CODE AS int) AS TIR, dbo.SC3420.SP4947 AS Date, 
                  CASE WHEN SC3420.SP4949 <> '     0   ' THEN 'ПовышСтрах' ELSE 'ОснСтрах' END AS VID, 
                  CASE WHEN dbo.SC3420.SP9214 = '714' THEN '4v' ELSE '' END AS TirType
      FROM         dbo.SC3420 INNER JOIN
                  dbo.SC5116 ON dbo.SC3420.SP3422 = dbo.SC5116.ID
       WHERE     (dbo.SC3420.SP4947 <> '01.01.1753')
```

Comment: i write in this way , and it also gave me null values in field TirType

Comment: If you specify a value in ELSE statement then TirType won't be NULL

Comment: i can put every value , it  dooesn't depend , but it gave me this value to all my field

Comment: but can u put 2 cases in a stored procedure , or how can i combine 2 cases in one case?

Comment: You can combine cases like this: `CASE WHEN 1 = 2 THEN 'Impossible' ELSE CASE WHEN 1 > 2 THEN 'More' ELSE 'Less' END END`

Comment: Or you could use the more conventional `CASE WHEN 1 = 2 THEN 'Impossible' WHEN 1 > 2 THEN 'More' ELSE 'Less' END`, and avoid too many levels of nesting.